# How can I mass rename all the form fields in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I made a PDF with many (like 100) fillable form fields. But I did it with copy and paste. Now all the form fields have the same name (Text1) and filling in one will fill in all the others with the same info.

Is there a script, program, or trick I can use to rename all those form fields without manually double clicking and renaming each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable with writing scripts, you may find this question on stackoverflow useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343657/is-it-possible-to-modify-pdf-form-field-names

You'll find code examples written in VBScript, VB.NET and CSharp.

Comment: cheers, I haven't written scripts in those languages but I'm comfortable trying to copy/paste my way through it :P Thanks for answering.